# How do i convert string percentage into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, yt-dlp

I am using a tkinter GUI with the yt-dlp library, when approaching to make a progress bar, I get a problem to conversing the str hook into a float

I have this string
`"\x1b[0;94m  0.0%\x1b[0m"`

that I need to turn in to a float into this:

`0.0`

I have tried using `.replace` but it only works up to 17.7, then I get errors such as:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\x1b[0;94m 17.7'`

How can I solve this "problem"?

Comment: Please share your code, so we can investigate why it stops at 17.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you provided seems to contain ANSI escape codes for color formatting. To extract the float value from this string you need to remove the ANSI escape codes and the percentage sign (%) and then convert the remaining string to a float.

```
import re

input_string = "\x1b[0;94m 17.7%\x1b[0m"

# Remove ANSI escape codes and percentage sign
extracted_string = re.sub(r'\x1b\[[0-9;]*m', '', input_string)
extracted_string = re.sub(r'%', '', extracted_string)
result = float(extracted_string)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming pattern is always the same, this could be a much better way to do so.

```py
import re

input_string = "\x1b[0;94m  17.7%\x1b[0m"
match = re.search(r'\b\d+\.\d+\b', input_string)
result = float(match.group())
print(result)
```

output:

```
17.7
```

Comment: I used your solution, but now it fail's at 57.6, don't worry another answer got it sorted out. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

To extract the float value from the string `"\x1b[0;94m  0.0%\x1b[0m,"` you can use regular expressions. The Python `re` module can help you achieve this. Here's how you can do it:

```py
import re

# Your input string
input_string = "\x1b[0;94m  0.0%\x1b[0m"

# Use regular expression to extract the float value
match = re.search(r'\d+\.\d+', input_string)

if match:
    extracted_float = float(match.group())
    print(extracted_float)
else:
    print("No float value found in the string.")
```

This code will find the first occurrence of a floating-point number in the string and convert it to a float. It should work for values like "0.0%" and "17.7%." If there are other patterns or variations in your input string, you may need to adjust the regular expression pattern accordingly.

**Explanation:**

**Regular Expressions (Regex):**
Imagine you have a magic tool for finding specific words or patterns in a big pile of text. This magic tool is called regex. With it, you can look for things like phone numbers, emails, or even numbers with decimals in a text document.

**The `re` Module in Python:**
In Python, there's a special box of tricks called the `re` module. It helps us use regex easily in our programs. Think of it like a toolbox that holds all the tools you need to work with regex.

**Pattern `r'\d+\.\d+'`:**
Now, let's talk about a specific trick you can do with regex. Imagine you're reading a book, and you want to find all the numbers with decimals, like "0.0" or "17.7." The `r'\d+\.\d+'` pattern is like a set of instructions for your magic tool (regex).

- `r'\d'` means "find any digit (from 0 to 9)."
- `+` means "keep finding more of the thing that came before (digits in this case)."
- `'\.'` means "find a dot (but remember, we need to put a backslash in front of it because a dot has a special meaning in regex)."
- `'\d+'` means "find more digits after the dot."

So, when you use this pattern, your magic tool will look for sequences of digits followed by a dot and then more digits. It helps you find numbers with decimals in a text, like "0.0%" or "17.7%."

This way, even if you're just starting with regex, you can use these patterns to find specific things in text documents. It's like a superpower for searching and working with text!